# Display Team Member Categories on Individual Team page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a website for a show that I am producing called Puppet Playlist. I am trying to find a way to display the categories that each team member is added into on their own individual pages.

Think of it this way, each artist will work on specific shows. Each show is it's own category. I have on each show page (portfolio posts) a team-member display which shows whatever team members are in that specific category.

What I'm hoping for, is a way to display the shows that the team member has worked on (meaning I want to display a list of the categories that the team member has been added to).

I've seen all of the get_the_categories and get_the_terms, but none seem to be working on my site, and it might partially be because I have no idea where to post them to. I'm using the Joyn Theme by Swift Ideas.

I would like a clear explanation of what to add and where to add it to in order to get the categories to display properly. I'm familiar with code, but am definitely not a coder/developer.

Thanks!

Comment: The website is currently housed at puppetplaylist.davidfertik.com

Comment: As it stands, have you added any team member to any category?